# Django how to mark_safe specific tag in text

Tags: django, django-templates

I have some text and I want to mark_safe only a specific tag. I wrote a filter, but cant understand how to return a right result.

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='strong_safe')
@stringfilter
def strong_safe(value):
    list = value.split()
    res = []
    for l in list:
        if l.startswith('<strong>'):
            res.append(mark_safe(l))
        else:
            res.append(l)
    return ' '.join(res)
```

I know that join convert save_str to str, also I read about format_html and format_html_join but can't understand how to use it in an appropriate way in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeeeap, after 3 hours I found a solution!

I move my filter code to a view and return a list to a template, then I iterate it and print.

view.py

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

body = 'some text with <strong>strong</strong>. this string is really <strong>strong</strong>'
list = body.split()
res = []
for l in list:
    if l.startswith('<strong>'):
        res.append(mark_safe(l))
    else:
        res.append(l)

return render(request, 'template/index.html', {'body': res})
```

index.html

```
{% for b in body %}
    {{ b }}
{% endfor %}
```

BTW, if you know another solution, please go ahead and share it!